# Annotations for enums in F#

Tags: enums, f#

I have an enum in F#:

```
type Gender = Undisclosed = 0 | Male = 1 | Female = 2
```

The equivalent C# code would be

```
public enum Gender
{
    Undisclosed,
    Male,
    Female
}
```

In fact, in C#, I can go one step better.  To use gender in a dropdown in a `cshtml` page, I can do this:

```
public enum Gender
{
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(LocalisedStrings), Name = "GenderUndisclosed")] Undisclosed,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(LocalisedStrings), Name = "GenderMale")] Male,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(LocalisedStrings), Name = "GenderFemale")] Female
}
```

Unfortunately, the F# compiler says that "attributes are not allowed here" if I try to add similar annotations to the F# enum members.  Is there a way around this?  I'd like to avoid creating a duplicate class and performing Automapper voodoo if I possibly can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a `|` before the attribute.

```
// Doesn't compile. "Attributes are not allowed here"
type Foo = [<Bar>] Baz = 0

// Compiles.
type Foo = | [<Bar>] Baz = 0
```

In your case, this would come out to:

```
type Gender = 
    | [<Display(ResourceType = typeof<LocalisedStrings>, Name = "GenderUndisclosed")>] Undisclosed = 0
    | [<Display(ResourceType = typeof<LocalisedStrings>, Name = "GenderMale")>] Male = 1
    | [<Display(ResourceType = typeof<LocalisedStrings>, Name = "GenderFemale")>] Female = 2
```

Comment: Great job.  Not sure who got there first, but I've marked yours as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
type Gender = 
    | [<Display>] Undisclosed = 0 
    | [<Display>] Male        = 1 
    | [<Display>] Female      = 2
```